# How to handle the redirection the url in loadrunner fails on 302 redirect

Tags: loadrunner

Basically the script sends one request for images which works fine. The second request submits form data to the server, however I now get 302 redirect. From here the rest of the script fails.When I re-recorded the script, recording works fine. I compared the message sent when recorded, to the message sent by LR on play back and they look the same. Same headers, same message.Thanks in advance..Its very urgent.i have tried  "IGNORE REDIRECTIONS=YES" i got a error Invalid value for the "IgnoreRedirections" argument 
What have I missed??
What should I try???

Comment: Ignoring server redirection does not look like a good idea. It would be better to analyze why the script is failing in the first place. There might be some cookies/correlations missing. Please provide a piece of the replay output log and a part of your script containing the failing line of code.

Comment: Agreed with tserg42.  Ignoring redirections will prevent the follow of a 301 or 302.  The root is likely with another issue, especially if you are replaying without handling any dynamic data or without checking for expected results and branching your code to cleanup when not found.

Comment: Thanq so much tserg42 & james pulley for replaying...Script got passed.